# translate string to downloadable txt file Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download

I have a table which is generated using a angular repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results">
    <td>
        <a download="Generated.txt" href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + {{result.generatedOutput}}>Download</a>
    </td>
<tr>
```

I have checked the results and result.generatedOutput has a value in it. But when ever i download the file it is blank. If i hardcode the value in like follows it works

```
<a download="Generated.txt" href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,sosososososlaksakldsa">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string should be added to href as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results">
    <td>
        <a download="Generated.txt" href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,{{result.generatedOutput}}">Download</a>
    </td>
<tr>
```

Also note that in Chrome this approach doesn't work, read more here:
[Force download of 'data:text/plain' URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468517/force-download-of-datatext-plain-url)

Comment: So that now works but i get a network error when i try to download.

Comment: In chrome that is

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-href` instead of `href`. This will force the `href` attribute to only be constructed when Angular has parsing the file, which includes the `{{}}` values. [More about ng-href here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).

```
<a download="Generated.txt" ng-href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,{{result.generatedOutput}}">Download</a>
```